# ignore missing files in loop - data did not show up

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have thousands of files as you can see the year range below. Some of the dates of the files are missing so I want to skip over them. But when I tried the method below, and calling `data_in`, the variable doesn't exist.  Any help would be truly appreciated. I am new to python. Thank you.

```
path = r'file path here' 
DataYears = ['2012','2013','2014', '2015','2016','2017','2018','2019', '2020']
Years = np.float64(DataYears)
NumOfYr = Years.size
DataMonths = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']
daysofmonth=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
for yy in range(NumOfYr):
    for mm in range (12):
        try:
            data_in = pd.read_csv(path+DataYears[yy]+DataMonths[mm]+'/*.dat', skiprows=4, header=None, engine='python')
            print('Reached data_in') # EDIT
            a=data_in[0] #EDIT
        except IOError:
            pass
            #print("File not accessible")
```

EDIT: Error added

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Directory/Documents/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    data_in = pd.read_csv(path+'.'+DataYears[yy]+DataMonths[mm]+'/*.cod', skiprows=4, header=None, engine='python')

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1126, in _make_engine
    self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2269, in __init__
    memory_map=self.memory_map,

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 431, in get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, errors="replace", newline="")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Directory/Documents/201201/*.dat'
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you try a file that doesnt exist? if so can you show the error and the full stack trace. If you dont get an error what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I want to do some calculation using `data_in` but when I tried to called `a=data_in[0]`  `print(a)`, I get: `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. I want to do a calculation for each file that exits.

Comment: But where in your code do you have `a=data_in[0]`? inside the try block? and if so where is your line `print(a)` after the try/except block? If so then when you fail to read a file with pd.read_csv you will fall in the except block so never call `a=data_in[0]` which means if after the try except block you try to use `print(a)` you will indeed get name error since `a` was never assigned since the code failed on pd.read_csv

Comment: Try adding prints to your code to help you understand what's happening and whether `data_in` is ever being created. For example beneath `data_in` add `print('Reached data_in')` and before `pass` add `print(IO_Error)`. And consider adding `except: print('Some other error occurred')` to catch errors that aren't `IOErrors`

Comment: @Jason I add the `print('Reached data_in')` and I get this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Directory/Documents/201201/*.data'`.  The format for most of my files are `/Directory/Documents/201201(datehere).dat`.

Comment: Can you add the full error to your original question? It seems that the file paths you're trying to create with `path+DataYears[yy]+DataMonths[mm]+'/*.dat'` are not correct. If you want to iterate over files which all reside in a the same directory a better/more robust approach would be to use the `glob` module to get a list of file paths and then to iterate over those.

Comment: Taking a closer look at the file your try to create `'/*.dat'` do you want the `*` to be expanded to match anything end in `.dat`? If so that's not going to be the case, the `*` will be interpreted literally as `*`.

Comment: @Jason, Using `glob` and after calculation, I am planning to plot it with the date range, there are some files with certain date are missing.  Is there a way to skip the missing dates.  Also all the files will be `.../20120101.dat`, `.../20120102.dat`, `.../20120105.dat`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean that there are some files where the _contents_ of the file is missing date information. Or do you mean that some dates are missing in your file names?

Comment: @Jason,  Each individual file is a day and some day, there is no data so there is no file for that day.

Comment: Okay I see, if there's no file then it's simpler- I'll write an answer to demonstrate what I was suggesting using `glob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt the code below to get a list of your date folders:

```
import glob

# Gives you a list of your folders with the different dates
folder_names = glob.glob("Directory/Documents/")
print(folder_names)
```

Then with the list of folder, you can iterate through there contents. If you just want a list of all `.dat` files can do something like:

```
import glob

# Gives you a list of your folders with the different dates
file_names = glob.glob("Directory/Documents/*/*.dat")
print(file_names)
```

The code above searches the contents of your directories so you bypass your problem with missing dates. The `print`s are there so you can see the results of `glob.glob()`.

Comment: If I take the average each day and plot it as a function of time for all the days in the year.  Will `glob` take care of the missing date?

Comment: @Tina No, these are quite separate tasks. First you need to find your files to read (`glob`), then you need to actually read the data in the files (`pandas`). Once you've read the data, depending on how it's structured you may or may not need to manipulate it (where you can do any interpolation etc.) (`pandas`). Once you have the data in the format you want to plot it then you can use something like `matplotlib` to create your visualisation.

Comment: Each module performs a specific task, the modules in brackets are suggestions but there are alternatives which may be more suitable depending on the specifics of the task you want to perform.